# Running python interpreter or language X in Emacs

Tags: emacs, window, buffer, interpreter

Every time I start the interpreter for a programming language (lets consider python in this case) emacs opens the interpreter in the window which is not current. Note that I have two windows open, so the interpreter is always opening in the opposite window that I am currently in. This is annoying because then I always have to switch windows after I open an interpreter...

1. How can I get the python interpreter to open in the current window inside emacs?
2. Can I solve this problem generally for other programs/shells/buffers that do not open in the current window?

   I note that this also happens frequently with other emacs commands (such as `C-h v` and the description of the variable opens in the window that is not current)

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Interpreter-buffers connect with a process. If not already there, it must be a different one than the buffer called from - otherwise the current buffers contents is lost.

You might be interested in org-mode, org-babel, which provides a way to insert results in current buffer when executing source-code.

With python-mode.el, set `py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p` to non-nil. After `M-x py-shell`, cursor is in new shell.

If `py-split-windows-on-execute-p` is nil, `M-x py-shell` should switch to Python shell without splitting the window. See more options if re-using an existing `py-shell` etc.

With python.el, `M-x run-python` switches into the Python-shell.

See also customizable variable `pop-up-windows`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood or I used the wrong vocabulary. I am talking about windows, like splitting the emacs window by entering `C-x 2`

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Extended the answer, as `py-split-windows-on-execute-p` seems the variable at stake.

Comment: Where would I find out about these variables for my other interpreters?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Recent python.el already switches with M-x run-python. Maybe upgrade?

Comment: I am using `python-mode.el` is there any difference in what you are talking about?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus With python-mode.el you should be able to customize it. If not, please give some details, resp. file a bug-report at `https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode`

Comment: I opened `python-mode.el` and searched for `py-split-windows-on-execute-p` and it does not exist. From the minibuffer I also tried `C-h v` and typed `py-split-windows-on-execute-p` and still did not find it. I am running emacs 24.3